# Error Init Kafka Client: kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to: dial tcp: lookup kafka on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, monitoring, kafka-exporter

```
C:\kafka>kubectl logs kafka-exporter-745f574c74-tzfn4
I0127 12:39:08.113890 1 kafka_exporter.go:792] Starting kafka_exporter (version=1.6.0, branch=master, revision=9d9cd654ca57e4f153d0d0b00ce36069b6a677c1)
F0127 12:39:08.890639 1 kafka_exporter.go:893] Error Init Kafka Client: kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to: dial tcp: lookup kafka.osm.svc.cluster.local on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host
```

below is the kafka-exporter-deployment.yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: kafka-exporter
namespace: default
spec:
replicas: 1
selector:
matchLabels:
app: kafka-exporter
template:
metadata:
labels:
app: kafka-exporter
spec:
containers:
- name: kafka-exporter
image: danielqsj/kafka-exporter:latest
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
args:
- --kafka.server=kafka.osm.svc.cluster.local:9092
- --web.listen-address=:9092
ports:
- containerPort: 9308
env:
- name: KAFKA_EXPORTER_KAFKA_CONNECT
value: kafka-broker-644794f4ff-8gmxb:9092
- name: KAFKA_EXPORTER_TOPIC_WHITELIST
value: samptopic
```

Kafka-exporter-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: kafka-exporter
namespace: default
spec:
selector:
app: kafka-exporter
ports:

name: http
port: 9308
targetPort: 9308
type: NodePort
```

Comment: Well, can you show the services that **are running** in the `osm` namespace? Error says `kafka` isn't one of them. And do you really need both `KAFKA_EXPORTER_KAFKA_CONNECT` and `--kafka.server`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. actually there is no namespace called  "osm" everything running on default namespace only .. and which one do  u suggest "- --kafka.server=kafka.osm.svc.cluster.local:9092
- --web.listen-address=:9092" or  - name: KAFKA_EXPORTER_KAFKA_CONNECT
value: kafka-broker-644794f4ff-8gmxb:9092 for mentioning kafka server details so that i will go ahead and do the changes

Comment: If there's no osm namespace, why are you using it as part of the DNS name? Where are those environment variables documented? I think you should remove both of them. Your web listen address also needs to be 9308, since that's your actual containerPort. And why not use Helm? https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter/tree/master/charts/kafka-exporter#helm-install

Answer (score 0):

> actually there is no namespace called "osm" everything running on default namespace

Refer [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services).

As the error says, there's no service `kafka` in an `osm` namespace (whether that exists, or not), that can be reached. Remove `.osm` from that address, or change it to `.default`, assuming that there really is a Service named `kafka` available at port 9092